# Monitoring fired Javascript events (regardless of browser)

Tags: javascript

I know this question has been answered before, but all the answers refer to browser-specific method. My question is simple:
Is there a way to monitor all fired events ( info I need is the fired event and the element that fired it) from withing the Javascript?

I thought of setting event listener for all events and all elements but this is highly unpractical and it wouldn't work with custom made events.

Comment: Instead of listening to all the events, why don't you work in a AOP-sort of fashion by injecting an aspect on all event listeners?

Answer (score -1):

There is something that can help you.

You can use  Objects.observe fo monitoring object

There  are also mutation [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) for certain dom element and [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

But if you really need to have all the events monitored you can redefine the addEvent function. I assume you need this only for debugging and testing something otherwise it is not really a good practice to do this.

```
// The magic 
var oldAddEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;

EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(eventName, eventHandler){
  // DO YOUR MAGIC
  oldAddEventListener.call(this, eventName, function(event) {
      // DO YOUR MAGIC
      eventHandler(event);
  });
};
```

More info on https://css-tricks.com/capturing-all-events/